# Rewrite rule change the URL structure

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect my old pages to my new updated link structure pages because the old ones are now giving 404

Old

```
domain.com/artist-some-name
```

New

```
domain.com/artist/some_name.html
```

Where the - and _ between some name is put there instead of a space
So basically i want to replace the - seperator with the / which i can with

```
RewriteRule ^artist-(.+)$ /artist/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

But i can't work out how i can change the some-name to some_name so it will redirect properly

EDIT
    RewriteRule ^artists-(.+)-(.+)$ /artist/$1_$2.html [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^artists-(.+)$ /artist/$1.html [R=301,L]

Seems like this works for both if spaces in url or not

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^artist-(.+)-(.+)$ /artist/$1_$2.html [R=301,L]

Comment: Yeah but some of the artists only have one word therefor they links won't have any - or _ symbols as there is no spaces

Comment: I think it needs another rule for replacing every `-` with `_`

Comment: Yeah not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Give these a try:

```
RewriteRule ^artist-([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)$ /artist/$1_$2.html [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^artist-([a-z]+)$ /artist/$1.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

You need to limit the wild cards so that only letters are included. If you need to include numbers ('digits' in regex), then you can add `0-9` just next to the `a-z`. Alternatively, you can use `\d+`, for short.